How do you solve a ghost skewb such as Tony Fisher's Golden Cube?
A ghost skewb is a bizarre Rubik's cube variant, where the faces are all unique, odd shapes. The faces are all the same color, so the puzzle is solved when it's a cube again instead of a mess. Rotation happens at different angles, and is sometimes blocked by the shape of the faces. Unlike a proper ghost cube, Rubik's cube 3x3 algorithms don't seem like they'll work.
Does this puzzle have algorithms? How do you solve it without taking it apart?
This is the puzzle solved:

